# When the powers of an element of a Finite Field generate a subfield?

Tags: abstract-algebra

As it is known, all the elements on a Finite Field GF($q$) of $q$ elements have an order $n \le q−1$ in such a way that being $\beta$ a given element: $β^n=1$. The set $F^∗={β0,\beta^1,⋯,\beta^{n−1}}$ is a commutative group under multiplication. The element whose order is $q−1$ is named the primitive element, $\alpha$. Every Finite Field has a primitive element and its powers generate the Field. Sometimes, $F^* \cup \{0\}$ is a subfield of GF($q$) as for $\beta = \alpha^5$ in GF($2^4$). What conditions should be accomplished in order to get a subfield from the successive powers of a given element, is that enough that the order is a prime or the power of a prime number?.

Comment: A field of $p^r$ elements ($p$ a prime) has subfields of order $p,p^2,\dots$ so for $\beta$ to generate the nonzero elements of a subfield $\beta$ must have order $p-1,p^2-1,\dots$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, that’s not right. A field of $p^r$ elements has subfields only of order $p^s$ for $s|r$. (Unless I misunderstood the burden of your comment?)

Comment: @Lubin, you're absolutely right, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Thank you guys, so the condition in order that the successive powers of a given element generate a subfield is that it has an order of $p^s - 1$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.